# How to generate password protected Excel file using BIRT?

Tags: java, excel, passwords, birt, birt-emitter

This is part of my code in eclipse to generate the Excel file. Based on BIRT.

```
if (ArrayUtils.contains(reportFormats, EXCEL)) {
    // set output options
    EXCELRenderOption options = new EXCELRenderOption();
    options.setOutputFormat("xls");
    options.setOutputFileName(reportName + ".xls");
    options.setSupportedImageFormats("PNG;GIF;JPG;BMP");
    renderTask.setRenderOption(options);
    renderTask.render();
}
```

I searched a lot on the internet, but cannot find the solution, please help.
Thanks, everyone.

Comment: I think you need to change the excel emitter. Seach for something like that. There is a lot to be found on this subject. If not, please clarify your problem, BIRT version etc.

Comment: @Jeroen Hi, thanks for the reply. The BIRT version is 4.4.1, when it generate the excel file, I wanna to add a password on the file, no one can modify the file.

Comment: does anyone know any possible solution, i cannot find any information about it.
please help